# When I change my image to absolute position, my image disappears

Tags: css, image, position, absolute

```
.BottomCloud {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200;
    margin-left: 300;
}

.TopCloud {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100;
    margin-right: 300;
}
```

I have tried changing the position to relative, but the clouds don't go where I need them to go

Comment: Try adding inset:0 to the position:absolute element. Then it will appear.

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: Look into using units when positioning. And we need to know your HTML structure and how any ancestors to the images are positioned.

Comment: </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello I'm Anthony</h1>
        <img class = "Mountain" src ="Images/mountain.png">
        <img class = "TopCloud" src ="Images/cloud.png">
        <img class = "BottomCloud" src ="Images/cloud.png">
        <div class="top-container">
            
        
        
        </div>
        <div class ="middle-container">

        </div>
        <div class ="bottom-container">
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
    
</html>

Comment: It appears when I put in inset: 0 however I want to move the cloud, not just have it in the corner

Comment: @AnthonyNewton you can move the cloud by using `left:50%; top:100px` or using css animations

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `position: absolute` can not work alone. You have to add `position:relative` to the parent. If I am not mistaken you are trying to make a page with some floating clouds. In that case, take a wrapper div, make it position relative. Here's the code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Hello I'm Anthony</h1>
  <img class = "Mountain" src ="Images/mountain.png"> 
  <img class = "TopCloud" src ="Images/cloud.png"> 
  <img class = "BottomCloud" src ="Images/cloud.png"> 
  <div class="top-container"> </div> 
  <div class ="middle-container"> </div> 
  <div class ="bottom-container"> </div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
   position:relative
 }
.TopCloud {
   position: absolute;
   Top:100px;
   Left:10%
   max-width:30%
 }
```

You just need to change the `top` and `left` values. `max-width` is not mandatory. All the best.